# Spring batch restart with jobparameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is it possible to restart the job for specific parameters in Spring batch?

I have two instances of failed job in meta-table. Each job is having its own job parameter. Now, I want to restart job with given parameter. Even though I pass the job parameter, it is always restarting only the last failed execution.

My job:

```
<batch:job id="JobA"  incrementer="runIdIncrementer">
    <batch:step id="abcde">
        <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <batch:chunk reader="Reader" writer="Writer" processor="Processor" commit-interval="100" />
        </batch:tasklet>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

I will start JobA with different parameters in two different instances. Say suppose JobA for 1234 account and JobA for 5678 account. Both instances were failed. Now I want restart JobA for 1234 account. But Spring batch is always restarting last failed excuetion irrespective of parameters.

**Edited**
Debugging the `CommandLineJobRunner` I found this code which always restarts the latest failed job irrespective of job parameters:

```
private JobExecution getLastFailedJobExecution(String jobIdentifier) {
    List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = getJobExecutionsWithStatusGreaterThan(jobIdentifier, BatchStatus.STOPPING);
    if (jobExecutions.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    }
    return jobExecutions.get(0);
}
```

Comment: Are you using spring-boot?

Comment: No i am not using spring boot

Answer (score 3):

We had the same issue and to me this looks like a flaw, especially when you compare how the SimpleJobLauncher evaluates the last job.

As you mentioned, getLasFailedJobExecution() does not take into account the parameters. (Which, at least in my opinion, is wrong. You can run the same job with different identifying parameters, but restarting would only work if only one of this runs failed.)

On the other hand, SimpleJobLauncher gets the last jobexecution based on the parameters:

```
public JobExecution run(final Job job, final JobParameters jobParameters)
        throws JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobRestartException, JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException,
        JobParametersInvalidException {
...

    JobExecution lastExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(job.getName(), jobParameters);
...
```

This is not consistent.

The way we fixed it was to implement our own CommandLineJobRunner that is derived from the CommandLineJobRunner, but you have to overwrite the whole start method and, therefore, you alse will have to copy a couple of private methods.

The whole restart part in the start method has to be changed in something like this:

```
        if (opts.contains("-restart")) {
            JobExecution lastExecution = jobRepository.getLastJobExecution(job.getName(), jobParameters);

            if (!jobExecution.getStatus().isGreaterThan(BatchStatus.STOPPING)) {
                throw new JobExecutionNotFailedException("No failed or stopped execution found for job="
                        + jobIdentifier);
            }
            jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
            jobName = jobExecution.getJobInstance().getJobName();
        }
```

**Edited**

Sometimes I really should read the javadoc...

In case of a restart, you could pass the executionid instead of the jobname. In this case, it will find the right execution to restart.

From the javadoch of the main method:

> restart: (optional) if the job has failed or stopped and the most
>        should be restarted. If specified then the jobIdentifier parameter can be
>        interpreted either as the name of the job **or the id of the job execution**
>        that failed.

Therefore, using the execution id in case of a restart will ensure that the right instance is restarted. In this case, you also don't have to provide any other parameters, since they will be taken from the last execution.

Comment: Thanks @Hansjoerg Wingeier.even we have solved the issue same way.

Comment: **Which, at least in my opinion, is wrong. You can run the same job with different identifying parameters, but restarting would only work if only one of this runs failed.** Does this mean that restart works for specific parameters

Comment: I just become aware that I missed something. Using the jobexecutionid instead of the jobname in case of a restart will do the trick. I changed my answer above

Comment: it has to ;-), at least that is what the code tells me. Make a breakpoint on line 388 (Version 3.05.RELEASE of spring-batch-core) of 'CommandLineJobRunner.getJobExecutionsWithStatusGreaterThan...' the call 'jobExplorer.getJobExecution(executionId)' has to return the JobExecution with the executionId you provided as second parameter.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass the **same set of parameters** for a second time to the CommandLineJobRunner - the job will be restarted at the point of failure.

The option '-restart' is an additional short cut provided to restart certain types of run (e.g. last failed run)